# How do I fix "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler" in Spring?

Tags: spring, wildfly, keycloak

I am trying to integrate the KeyCloak Spring Security adapter into an application, but I am seeing exceptions like this:

```
Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.<init>(Lorg\/keycloak\/adapters\/spi\/UserSessionManagement;Lorg\/keycloak\/adapters\/AdapterDeploymentContext;Lorg\/keycloak\/adapters\/spi\/HttpFacade;)V\n\tat org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:80)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was that the Wildfly server I was deploying the Spring application to already had the KeyCloak subsystem enabled (with a much older version of KeyCloak) to handle traditional servlet authorization. My Spring app was having class loading issues relating to an old version of KeyCloak configured in Wildfly and a new version of the spring security adapter.

The solution was to exclude the keycloak subsystem from my Spring app with this in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="keycloak"/>
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```